How to find congruence of xor equation through its products?
My equation starts as a simple xor of 8 bit numbers.
$k3_i = p_i \oplus c_i$
then we know that $k3$ is derived from a 16 bit value like this:
$x_i = a_i | 3$
$k3_i = \frac{(x_i*(x_i \pm 1)}{256}\, mod \, 256$
Now they are 256 possible values for $a_i$.
Let's say that i have first 8 bits of $a_i$ and i wanna find the last 8 bits of $a_i$ without having to brute force, So i went back to $k3_i = c_i \oplus p_i$ then generate another 256 possible values but these weren't a product of $k3_i$ but $c_i$ instead.
So by definition the products of $k3_i$ xor products of $c_i$ should produce products of $p_i$.
So i used real numbers.
$c_i = 0x58$
$p_i = 0x1C$
$a_i = 0x2f17$
And the products:
0x94 0x140c 0xa88
0x95 0x140d 0xa89
0x96 0x140e 0xa8a
0x97 0x140f 0xa8b
0xd28 0x14c8 0xbf4
0xd29 0x14c9 0xbf5
0xd2a 0x14ca 0xbf6
0xd2b 0x14cb 0xbf7
0xfd0 0x17c4 0xd1c
0xfd1 0x17c5 0xd1d
0xfd2 0x17c6 0xd1e
0xfd3 0x17c7 0xd1f
0x1314 0x193c 0x1730
0x1315 0x193d 0x1731
0x1316 0x193e 0x1732
0x1317 0x193f 0x1733
0x1f24 0x1c4c 0x1a78
0x1f25 0x1c4d 0x1a79
0x1f26 0x1c4e 0x1a7a
0x1f27 0x1c4f 0x1a7b
0x2e9c 0x1c94 0x1ad8
0x2e9d 0x1c95 0x1ad9
0x2e9e 0x1c96 0x1ada
0x2e9f 0x1c97 0x1adb
0x37fc 0x1f30 0x20b0
0x37fd 0x1f31 0x20b1
0x37fe 0x1f32 0x20b2
0x37ff 0x1f33 0x20b3
0x380c 0x26ac 0x242c
0x380d 0x26ad 0x242d
0x380e 0x26ae 0x242e
0x380f 0x26af 0x242f
0x404c 0x28b0 0x2958
0x404d 0x28b1 0x2959
0x404e 0x28b2 0x295a
0x404f 0x28b3 0x295b
0x4170 0x29b8 0x2b48
0x4171 0x29b9 0x2b49
0x4172 0x29ba 0x2b4a
0x4173 0x29bb 0x2b4b
0x41c0 0x2b98 0x2bf8
0x41c1 0x2b99 0x2bf9
0x41c2 0x2b9a 0x2bfa
0x41c3 0x2b9b 0x2bfb
0x4420 0x2f14 0x2dd4
0x4421 0x2f15 0x2dd5
0x4422 0x2f16 0x2dd6
0x4423 0x2f17 0x2dd7
0x4aac 0x3408 0x2ee8
0x4aad 0x3409 0x2ee9
0x4aae 0x340a 0x2eea
0x4aaf 0x340b 0x2eeb
0x4ba8 0x3544 0x3068
0x4ba9 0x3545 0x3069
0x4baa 0x3546 0x306a
0x4bab 0x3547 0x306b
0x50e0 0x38a4 0x35c0
0x50e1 0x38a5 0x35c1
0x50e2 0x38a6 0x35c2
0x50e3 0x38a7 0x35c3
0x5688 0x3dc0 0x3820
0x5689 0x3dc1 0x3821
0x568a 0x3dc2 0x3822
0x568b 0x3dc3 0x3823
0x5b40 0x3fdc 0x3f10
0x5b41 0x3fdd 0x3f11
0x5b42 0x3fde 0x3f12
0x5b43 0x3fdf 0x3f13
0x6134 0x4020 0x429c
0x6135 0x4021 0x429d
0x6136 0x4022 0x429e
0x6137 0x4023 0x429f
0x6190 0x43bc 0x44e0
0x6191 0x43bd 0x44e1
0x6192 0x43be 0x44e2
0x6193 0x43bf 0x44e3
0x6a74 0x4710 0x4bfc
0x6a75 0x4711 0x4bfd
0x6a76 0x4712 0x4bfe
0x6a77 0x4713 0x4bff
0x6db8 0x4928 0x4f40
0x6db9 0x4929 0x4f41
0x6dba 0x492a 0x4f42
0x6dbb 0x492b 0x4f43
0x6e5c 0x49e4 0x4fc4
0x6e5d 0x49e5 0x4fc5
0x6e5e 0x49e6 0x4fc6
0x6e5f 0x49e7 0x4fc7
0x6eb4 0x4ce0 0x516c
0x6eb5 0x4ce1 0x516d
0x6eb6 0x4ce2 0x516e
0x6eb7 0x4ce3 0x516f
0x6f98 0x5404 0x5494
0x6f99 0x5405 0x5495
0x6f9a 0x5406 0x5496
0x6f9b 0x5407 0x5497
0x7748 0x551c 0x56ec
0x7749 0x551d 0x56ed
0x774a 0x551e 0x56ee
0x774b 0x551f 0x56ef
0x77f0 0x5740 0x5a50
0x77f1 0x5741 0x5a51
0x77f2 0x5742 0x5a52
0x77f3 0x5743 0x5a53
0x7800 0x6250 0x6714
0x7801 0x6251 0x6715
0x7802 0x6252 0x6716
0x7803 0x6253 0x6717
0x7ae8 0x6c2c 0x6c00
0x7ae9 0x6c2d 0x6c01
0x7aea 0x6c2e 0x6c02
0x7aeb 0x6c2f 0x6c03
0x7bc4 0x7400 0x6d44
0x7bc5 0x7401 0x6d45
0x7bc6 0x7402 0x6d46
0x7bc7 0x7403 0x6d47
0x7c68 0x7684 0x6ecc
0x7c69 0x7685 0x6ecd
0x7c6a 0x7686 0x6ece
0x7c6b 0x7687 0x6ecf
0x8754 0x7a18 0x70a4
0x8755 0x7a19 0x70a5
0x8756 0x7a1a 0x70a6
0x8757 0x7a1b 0x70a7
0x902c 0x7b38 0x718c
0x902d 0x7b39 0x718d
0x902e 0x7b3a 0x718e
0x902f 0x7b3b 0x718f
0x9760 0x7d34 0x81e4
0x9761 0x7d35 0x81e5
0x9762 0x7d36 0x81e6
0x9763 0x7d37 0x81e7
0x9944 0x8674 0x825c
0x9945 0x8675 0x825d
0x9946 0x8676 0x825e
0x9947 0x8677 0x825f
0x9ca4 0x8764 0x83d0
0x9ca5 0x8765 0x83d1
0x9ca6 0x8766 0x83d2
0x9ca7 0x8767 0x83d3
0x9e80 0x87a8 0x8b60
0x9e81 0x87a9 0x8b61
0x9e82 0x87aa 0x8b62
0x9e83 0x87ab 0x8b63
0xa27c 0x8a9c 0x8c04
0xa27d 0x8a9d 0x8c05
0xa27e 0x8a9e 0x8c06
0xa27f 0x8a9f 0x8c07
0xa330 0x8ab4 0x8cc8
0xa331 0x8ab5 0x8cc9
0xa332 0x8ab6 0x8cca
0xa333 0x8ab7 0x8ccb
0xacb0 0x8bd0 0x9280
0xacb1 0x8bd1 0x9281
0xacb2 0x8bd2 0x9282
0xacb3 0x8bd3 0x9283
0xade4 0x9288 0xa1b8
0xade5 0x9289 0xa1b9
0xade6 0x928a 0xa1ba
0xade7 0x928b 0xa1bb
0xb7f4 0x9360 0xa398
0xb7f5 0x9361 0xa399
0xb7f6 0x9362 0xa39a
0xb7f7 0x9363 0xa39b
0xb804 0x93fc 0xac08
0xb805 0x93fd 0xac09
0xb806 0x93fe 0xac0a
0xb807 0x93ff 0xac0b
0xbd3c 0x996c 0xae84
0xbd3d 0x996d 0xae85
0xbd3e 0x996e 0xae86
0xbd3f 0x996f 0xae87
0xbd6c 0x9a80 0xb1a0
0xbd6d 0x9a81 0xb1a1
0xbd6e 0x9a82 0xb1a2
0xbd6f 0x9a83 0xb1a3
0xbda0 0x9eec 0xb534
0xbda1 0x9eed 0xb535
0xbda2 0x9eee 0xb536
0xbda3 0x9eef 0xb537
0xbe18 0xa278 0xb570
0xbe19 0xa279 0xb571
0xbe1a 0xa27a 0xb572
0xbe1b 0xa27b 0xb573
0xbf38 0xa2d8 0xb67c
0xbf39 0xa2d9 0xb67d
0xbf3a 0xa2da 0xb67e
0xbf3b 0xa2db 0xb67f
0xc2ec 0xa354 0xbe74
0xc2ed 0xa355 0xbe75
0xc2ee 0xa356 0xbe76
0xc2ef 0xa357 0xbe77
0xcb10 0xb158 0xbf64
0xcb11 0xb159 0xbf65
0xcb12 0xb15a 0xbf66
0xcb13 0xb15b 0xbf67
0xd8c8 0xb348 0xc128
0xd8c9 0xb349 0xc129
0xd8ca 0xb34a 0xc12a
0xd8cb 0xb34b 0xc12b
0xd9d4 0xb3f8 0xc2b4
0xd9d5 0xb3f9 0xc2b5
0xd9d6 0xb3fa 0xc2b6
0xd9d7 0xb3fb 0xc2b7
0xda84 0xb6cc 0xcc0c
0xda85 0xb6cd 0xcc0d
0xda86 0xb6ce 0xcc0e
0xda87 0xb6cf 0xcc0f
0xdacc 0xb6e8 0xd13c
0xdacd 0xb6e9 0xd13d
0xdace 0xb6ea 0xd13e
0xdacf 0xb6eb 0xd13f
0xdd8c 0xb868 0xd44c
0xdd8d 0xb869 0xd44d
0xdd8e 0xb86a 0xd44e
0xdd8f 0xb86b 0xd44f
0xe3dc 0xb98c 0xd590
0xe3dd 0xb98d 0xd591
0xe3de 0xb98e 0xd592
0xe3df 0xb98f 0xd593
0xe650 0xb9a0 0xdb54
0xe651 0xb9a1 0xdb55
0xe652 0xb9a2 0xdb56
0xe653 0xb9a3 0xdb57
0xe678 0xbb24 0xdeac
0xe679 0xbb25 0xdead
0xe67a 0xbb26 0xdeae
0xe67b 0xbb27 0xdeaf
0xe6d8 0xbd70 0xebf0
0xe6d9 0xbd71 0xebf1
0xe6da 0xbd72 0xebf2
0xe6db 0xbd73 0xebf3
0xe7bc 0xca5c 0xf218
0xe7bd 0xca5d 0xf219
0xe7be 0xca5e 0xf21a
0xe7bf 0xca5f 0xf21b
0xeb64 0xd3f4 0xf324
0xeb65 0xd3f5 0xf325
0xeb66 0xd3f6 0xf326
0xeb67 0xd3f7 0xf327
0xf558 0xdd90 0xf338
0xf559 0xdd91 0xf339
0xf55a 0xdd92 0xf33a
0xf55b 0xdd93 0xf33b
0xf7f8 0xf3f0 0xf7dc
0xf7f9 0xf3f1 0xf7dd
0xf7fa 0xf3f2 0xf7de
0xf7fb 0xf3f3 0xf7df
0xf808 0xf5d4 0xfbbc
0xf809 0xf5d5 0xfbbd
0xf80a 0xf5d6 0xfbbe
0xf80b 0xf5d7 0xfbbf
0xf91c 0xfe7c 0xffa8
0xf91d 0xfe7d 0xffa9
0xf91e 0xfe7e 0xffaa
0xf91f 0xfe7f 0xffab

Here my target is $0x2f17$ (in the middle column) which when xored with a value in left column and the value in right column it should produce zero.
So why $0x4423 \oplus  0x2f17 \oplus 0x2dd7 \neq 0$
What am i missing?

Yes the products should be congruent but you are assuming that the $list1[i] \oplus list2[i] \oplus list3[i] = 0$ which is wrong because the position $i$ is not guaranteed to be the corresponding index in a list, So you need to find the pattern in index of values that will satisfy $k3 = c \oplus p$.
The solution will be found when you iterate through each value from list3[] xor it with your target and check if your result is in list1[].
